# Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Мой запрос в базу:

```
Select `username`, `email`, `type`,`role`
From users
inner join usertoken on users.idUser = usertoken.Users_idUser
union
select `Like`,`username`,`nameQuiz`
from `like`
inner join `users` on `like`.`Users_idUser` = `users`.`idUser`
inner join `quiz` on `like`.`Quiz_idQuiz` = `quiz`.`idQuiz`
```

Ответ:

> Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number
>   of columns

[image: Users]

Таблица `users`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таблица `like`

И

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И `quiz`

Comment: В union есть обязательное требование: количество столбцов, их названия (порядок) и типы должны совпадать. Используйте алиасы, а если данных в одной таблице нет используйте константы типа 0, Null

Comment: Перевод ошибки: выборки содержат разное колличество столбцов. Смотрите каждый отдельный select на число столбцов. В случае "не знаю что должно быть в недостающем столбце"  - дополняйте null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Существуют два основных правила, регламентирующие порядок использования оператора UNION:

- Число и порядок извлекаемых столбцов должны совпадать во всех объединяемых запросах;
- Типы данных в соответствующих столбцах должны быть совместимы.

Определения столбцов, данные из которых извлекаются в объединяемых запросах, не должны совпадать, однако должны быть совместимыми путём неявного преобразования.

Используйте алиасы, а если данных в одной таблице нет используйте константы типа 0, Null

```
Select 
    `username`,
    0 as `like`,
    `email`,
    `type`,
    `role`,
    null as `nameQuiz`
From users
inner join usertoken on users.idUser = usertoken.Users_idUser
union
select
    `username`,
    `Like`,
    null as `email`,
    null as `type`,
    null as role,
    `nameQuiz`
from `like`
inner join `users` on `like`.`Users_idUser` = `users`.`idUser`
inner join `quiz` on `like`.`Quiz_idQuiz` = `quiz`.`idQuiz`
```

Ссылки по теме:

- [wikipedia про SQL Union](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(SQL))

PS Расставляйте поля по одному на строке - так визуально легче контролировать правильность запроса.

Comment: Алиасы не обязательно совпадения. Типы - желательно что б совпали, конвертация будет происходить по первому и могут быть неприятности.

Comment: @nick_n_a Да, я вот уже перечитываю статью, вспоминаю такие мелочи. Просто привык визуально контролировать правильность запроса именно расстановкой по порядку строк.

Comment: Особую осторожность следует проявлять, используя в первом подзапросе литералы. В примере используется ``0 as `like` `` - если во втором подзапросе соответствующее поле имеет нецелый тип (ну там decimal или double), будут неприятности. В этом случае крайне желательно явно определять тип, т.е. использовать, скажем ``CAST(0 AS DECIMAL) as `like` ``.